# How to create 1-100 ppm ethanol gas?

Tags: home-experiment, alcohols

I am trying to use [TGS 2602](http://www.figarosensor.com/products/2602pdf.pdf) sensor of air contaminants. I would like to test if my circuit is working as intended. For that purpose I need to generate fumes of one of the gases the can be detected by the sensor.

[image: TGS 2602 sensitivity characteristics]

I thought that I would go for ethanol. I tried holding vodka soaked cotton ball near the sensor - to no avail. Later on I tried spilling vodka around the circuit and placing more vodka soaked cotton balls around. I also covered the whole thing with a cardboard box (with gaps at the bottom between table and the box). Again there was no considerable effect. Vodka is essentially ~40% ethanol and water mix (by volume).

Can you say by that short description that I managed to generate between 1 and 100 ppm ethanol gas? If not, can you propose a robust and safe method of producing such a gas?

Please be aware how the sensor looks. It is enclosed in a metallic case with small holes on the top surface.

[image: TGS 2602 sensor]

Comment: Are you certain that the wiring and power supply 5 V DC for sensing and for heating are correct? You might want to look at the [datasheet](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?PHPSESSID=cmff9c9cpspn6vqm4v00s4rde5&action=dlattach;topic=281583.0;attach=119843).

Comment: @Klaus Warzecha - that is what I am trying to establish. I am using a somewhat more complicated circuit, because I am using digital rather than analog reader. Anyway when I replace the sensor with resistors (~57 ohm for the heater and ~10k or ~100k ohm for the sensor itself) the circuit seems to work - nevertheless I am not 100% sure that it is functioning as intended, therefore I would like to create a testing environment in which I should have prior knowledge that sensor should be sensing something if it was working correctly.

Comment: How to do it, and how to do it cheap are two very different problems.

Comment: If the 40% alcohol solution came to vapor-liquid equilibrium at room temperature , then the vapor concentration of ethanol should have been on the order of 2%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Waving a vodka soaked cotton ball near the sensor is sufficient to generate the required fumes. It was the circuit that was problematic - I did a subsequent testing with analog reader (voltmeter to be specific).